# Absolute positioning multiple elements without co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create simple java script menu.

I have two inner ul elements positioned absolutely to a relatively positioned div element. What ever is the case I am not able make the ul inline-blocks come next to each other. It seems the second block gets drawn on top of the first block. I also want to make the menu come to the right side of the screen.

I even gave width has 100% for the ul elements. Everything works fine until I add the position:absolute; to the ul elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/FhV8c/3/

```
<div id="izmenu">   
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-heading"><a href="#">home</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-heading"><a href="#">login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#izmenu {
 position: relative; 
 float:right;
}

#izmenu ul {
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 list-style: none;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
}

#izmenu ul li 
{
     padding: 0 0 0 0;
     margin: 0 0 0 0; 
}

 #izmenu a {
    background-color: #006899;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 0 0 0; 
}
```

Comment: What is the expected result? (What do you want it to look like?)

Comment: since there are both absolute, they will share same space by defaut starting from top left of parent.

Comment: Please find this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FhV8c/10/

Comment: That doesn't really explain what you are after.

Comment: From the fiddle I dont want the bottom H1 move down when I hover over the login menu. And at the same time I want the menu to float on the right side of the screen

Answer (score 1):

How about floating the elements?

```
#izmenu ul {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  display:block;
  float:left;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhV8c/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Both elements are being positioned *relative* to the same div.  One way to do what you want is to give the ul's id's then set their `right` position like so:

```
#one {
  right: 0
}

#two {
  right: 60px;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/FhV8c/6/